# Make multicolor dynamic text in textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css

My question is simple. but didn't get solution. 
I have one textarea. like:

```
<textarea style="height: 70px; width: 99%;"></textarea>
```

And Jquery like:

```
var text = 'Hello... \n World \n othertext';
$('textarea').attr('value', text);
```

Now, i like to make different formatting for `Hello` , `World` and `othertext`. 
 Suppose `Hello` with `color:red` and `font-size:15px;`, and World has `color:yellow` and `font-size:20px;` and so on.

So, how can i set using either css or jquery?

[Fiddle Link.](http://jsfiddle.net/pdXRx/617/)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible within a single `textarea` as you can only set one font style for the entire element. You would psobably need to use a contenteditable div, or a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Am curious to know why do you want this... I mean is there any real world requirement which I feel is weird

Comment: I just want to add text in textarea dynamic. atleast if it is possible with different text variable. like `text1 = 'hello'`, `text2 = 'world'` and so on.

Comment: color and different font properties are not possible in textarea, use editor for that.

Comment: regarding your comment on different text variable you can use string split using space to create different variable using string entered in textarea

Comment: @Yogesh string split how? can you show any example?

Comment: And even i check then it is also not work in input text also.

Comment: i saw your example you want out put in text area which is not possible but if split var text = 'Hello... \n World \n othertext'; using '\n' and write some logic to add this text with HTML in div and this div will look like textarea

Comment: as shown in below example by Krishnadas PC

Comment: @Yogesh Sorry but i can't use div instead of textarea. So, is this called limitation of html?

Comment: Textarea is for plain text  not for html text

Comment: you can try http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is possible with a text area. Below is my sample code with editable div using java script. JS fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/pckrishnadas88/ec4Lnn22/

```js
$('.editable').each(function(){
    this.contentEditable = true;
});
```

```css
div.editable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    color:red;
}
div.editable span{
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable">editable<span> span content</span></div>
```

Comment: Yes i know that it is possible with div.